# Need to add new simple plugin into hawtio

Tags: hawtio

First time I am using **hawtio**(2.7.1). I want to add a new simple plugin into hawtio. Now I am using hawtio **standalone jar**.  How to add new plugin in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will release [Hawtio 2.8.0](https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/blob/master/CHANGES.md#change-log), which will support custom plugin, soon.